# How to call the graph from which the vertices and edges outside the fundamental cycles are deleted?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a special name of the graph from which the vertices and the edges outside the fundamental cycles are deleted?

Comment: So you mean the subgraph induced from the vertices in a given fundamental cycle?

Comment: No, I think of the subgraph induced from the vertices and edges of ALL the fundamental cycles.

Comment: Oh ok. So in the end I think you'd only be deleting bridges and then any resulting isolated vertices. So in the end, you'd have the maximum subgraph with respect to the property that each component is $2$-edge-connected. Not sure what the name of that is (Google turned up nothing).